# how to auto sorted result from vlookup(google sheet)

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have this formula on google sheet

```
VLOOKUP(upper(J2:J),colorState!A:B,{2}*sign(row(J2:J)),FALSE)
```

and I want it to sort the result ascending automatically when I add new data or edit(like arrayformula)

Is there anyway or any formula to do that? (I know that there's `SORT` formula but I'm not sure how to use it together)

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I understand what you need :)

Essentially what I understand is that you would like to recreate the "main" sheet but have it automatically ordered by the 'color' column when new data is added.  I don't have any idea how to do this to the raw data but you can mirror the raw data by creating another sheet (name 'mainmirror') and in cell A1 just enter this formula:

```
=query(main!$A:$R,"select * order by P ASC",-1)
```

It will take you 2 seconds to reformat with a filter view, and you'll be left with a mirror of 'main' that is always sorted by column P and should remain current as data is added.

Hopefully this is an acceptable workaround.  Other option would be to use a script but this is less tedious if it's suitable.

Side note: this method will turn your values into strings to mirror them on the duplicate sheet, so on the 'main' sheet I would recommend changing the cell format of column P to a custom number format, 00, which will ensure there's a leading 0 if there's only one digit.  this will cause the strings in the mirror to sort correctly, instead of 1,11,12,2,3,4,etc.  If you're expecting column P to have 3 digit value, make the number format 000 accordingly.

Comment: I use this syntax to compare value in column J with another sheet(colorState) which located in column A of colorState,if it is the same value,will get the value in column B of colorState and I want it to sort ascending automatically(now I have to select SORT A-Z in the filter everytime I refresh data from add-on). you can see my sheet here [color column-P] https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1484Du4tKgbuFSYBBKXg83eqCkPUDq2oZhiW-ycSN1Q8/edit#gid=0

Comment: I have edited the answer to suit your purpose, let me know if this will work. If not it might be time to make a script.